# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'node:fs'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic-framework

When i run Ionic generate page, i got this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
```

It Happened after i change my node js version to 14.15.0. i forgot what version of node js that i used before. and i cant find any solution anywhere about this problem. i've been trying to change node version to other version but it just gave me new different kind of error.

Here is my package.json looks like

```
 {
  "name": "sbh_mobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.41.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/device": "^5.45.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^5.45.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^5.46.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/ionic-webview": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/native-geocoder": "^5.45.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/onesignal": "^5.44.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/screen-orientation": "^6.2.0",
    "@capacitor-community/background-geolocation": "git+https://github.com/pdrhlik/background-geolocation.git",
    "@capacitor-community/camera-preview": "^3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "3.3.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^1.2.4",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.3.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.0.1",
    "@capacitor/local-notifications": "^1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/network": "^1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.3",
    "@capgo/native-market": "^1.1.11",
    "@coreui/angular": "^4.2.14",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^4.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/aes-256": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/themeable-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/uid": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.3.7",
    "@ionic/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^3.0.6",
    "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.1",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.14",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-uid": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.27",
    "ionic-keyboard-assist": "^4.0.2",
    "jsqr": "^1.4.0",
    "lottie-web": "^5.10.1",
    "ngx-lottie": "^7.0.4",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.7.6",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^8.4.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.9.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^8.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Please, help me to solve this problem... thank you

Comment: Each exception typically also has a stacktrace, which shows you where the exception occured ...

Comment: But it seems the `node:fs` prefix isn't supported in node 14.15 for commonjs modules. Update to at least 14.18 or 16.0.

Comment: i just change it to node 14.18.2 and the node:fs is gone. but i still have this error this.tree.readText is not a function
[ERROR] Could not generate page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. Fortunately I have the older folder of my project. and I match all the `devDependencies` version. I found out that version of my `@ionic/angular-toolkit` in my older folder is ^4.0.0 and the new one is `^6.0.0`. I don't know how it change. but I already downgrade it to `4.0.0` and the ionic g page is now working fine.....

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the node modules folder and run npm i, that should generate a new node folder with your updated node version.